# How to use IHardwareService in your code?

Tags: java, android, hardware

Is there a way to use somehow `IHardwareService`.
It is not visible, but documentation concerning it can be found. So looks like there should be some way to use it.

Could you please advice how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From an SDK application, you don't use `IHardwareService`. It is not available in the SDK.

If you are creating your own device or are otherwise modifying Android firmware, it should be possible to access it -- just use [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) to find places which reference it and see how they use it.